# How can I keep a shopping cart populated when the user navigates away from the 'cart' page, wihtout using a database

Tags: php, session, shopping-cart

I am building a shopping cart with php, and i have all the items able to pass through to the cart page. However, if the user were to navigate away from the page, all the items disappear. I know that I can use  to begin a session, but how do i persist data in the session without using a database?

Should I learn HTML5 session-storage?

---

Thanks, Eric. I agree, 'if it aint broke then dont try to fix it'...so, how exactly do I read/ write data to the $_SESSION array. I have read the php manual page, but still am at a loss...my data doesnt transfer. Here's my code:

```
    <?php session_start();
$mytext = $_SESSION['mytext']; 
    $mytext1 = $_SESSION['mytext1']; 
    $mytext2 = $_SESSION['mytext2']; 
    $mytext3 = $_SESSION['mytext3'];

$price = $_SESSION['price']; 
    $price1 = $_SESSION['price1']; 
    $price2 = $_SESSION['price2']; 
    $price3 = $_SESSION['price3']; 

    $total = $mytext * $price;     
    $total1 = $mytext1 * $price1; 
    $total2 = $mytext2 * $price2; 
    $total3 = $mytext3 * $price3;
```

?>'

Comment: why bother with html5? standard PHP sessions (using a single cookie) have worked for years without trouble, and are supported universally by any cookie-enabled browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the PHP $_SESSION variable doesn't use a proper database or need you to install anything in addition to PHP.  It will simply store each users session data in a file on your server.

After calling [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) you can simply read/write data to the `$_SESSION` array as you would any other array. Look at the [`session_start()` page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) for an example.

No, I wouldn't do this in HTML 5.  PHP sessions have been working well for years and won't have any browser compatibility issues.

**EDIT**

Are you writing to the array first?  If you haven't put the items in, you won't get anything out.  You'll notice that on the example in the linked page, there are two pages in play.  The first page assigns **to** the session array.  In your code, you only try to take things out of the session array.  Until you add items to it, you won't get anything out of it.

Comment: thanks, but your code had a ton of bugs. You should give it time before you paste any more 'answers'. You could trip up those of us who are serious about programming.

Comment: Ha ha ha. Wow. Stack Overflow isn't a place for people to write your code for you.  What I posted wasn't complete code, but could have been used as some guide lines.  I tried to answer questions you hadn't asked yet. I'll simplify to target your question better.  You could post more detail about how it didn't work as well.

Comment: You're right. my bad...tough day at work. anyways, I guess php's foreach statement doesn't include 'in' I think it only covers 'as'...
Idon't know what php syntaxis that would populate an array. I tried to send a message earlier, but it didn't update to the page. THanks for your feedback and help, though, Eric. You know alot more than I do...

Comment: Eric, if you're still there...I found a php function to search an array that would would as would as foreach in function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: Oh, my bad.  I work in a few languages.  One of the other uses `in`.  If you were still looking at my original sample code, you would also need to switch the order of the variables in the foreach statement.  In php, the array goes first. :-/  That was a bit sloppy of me. Sorry.